# "imagesc" function belongs to which packages and libraries in r?

Tags: r, matlab

After forming the matrix( which is my resultant image ) from certain data I am trying to display the image using the "imagesc" in r. The same thing I already had done in Matlab. To do the same in r I found out "imagesc" in r. but when I use this function it is showing the following error message

```
No documentation for ‘imagesc’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??imagesc’
```

Even I already incorporated

```
library(R.matlab)
```

please help me to resolve the issue? I am a beginner in r programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the function `imagesc` in the wrong package.

The package `R.matlab` doesn't have such function (see [R.matlab](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.matlab/versions/3.6.2)).

You can find it in the [matlab package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/matlab/versions/1.0.2), though.

So just do:

```
install.packages("matlab")
library(matlab)
```

and you'll be good to go with `imagesc`.

That said, if your task is going to be a recurrent one, I think it's a good idea to use **native** R solutions, instead of Matlab's. In such case, you may want to check `ggplot2::geom_tile`.

Check this image, for instance: [image: geom_tile example]

Comment: surely I will check the ggplot2::geom_tile also, thanks for your help.